# Add external jar in gradle

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

How can I add an external library in gradle? My `build.gradle` contains:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

My root folder is `/FORGE/`. I want to add `/FORGE/build/libs/spigot.jar` as a dependency.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub%3afile_dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/spigot.jar')
}
```

The above will add the `libs/spigot.jar` file to the `compile` configuration. You can of course add it to any other configuration (runtime, etc.).

Note that using `build/libs` is an extremely bad idea, since the whole build directory will be deleted as soon as you execute `gradle clean`. The build directory is used to store artifacts generated by the build.

Comment: I create Folder lib(FORGE/build/lib) and put spigot.jar. My build gardle:     dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
        compile files('lib/spigot.jar')
    } and have error http://i.gyazo.com/62470133c325b501287feae846adea6e.png Line 15: compile files('lib/spigot.jar')

Comment: Read my answer again. files('lib/spigot.jar') will look for the file in lib/spigot.jar, not in build/lib/spigot.jar. You shouldn't put anything into build, because the build dir is for produced artifact, and will be deleted by gradle clean.

Comment: Ok, moved spigot.jar to FORGE/lib/ and have same error on line 15: files('lib/spigot.jar') http://i.gyazo.com/62470133c325b501287feae846adea6e.png.

Comment: Do you actually have a configuration named "compile"? If you have a configuration named "classpath" and that's where you want to add the jar, then use `classpath files('lib/spigot.jar')`.

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath files('libs/carftbukkit.jar', 'libs/netty-all-4.0.17.Final.jar', 'libs/commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar', 'libs/jinput.jar', 'libs/lwjgl.jar', 'libs/lwjgl_util.jar', 'libs/commons-io-2.4.jar', 'libs/minecraft_server.1.7.2.jar')
    } Work, thanks

Comment: Will this work in production? does the underlying class-loader pick-up and load these external JARs as dependencies? or is this only during development?

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld gradle is a build tool. It's used to compile, assemble, publish, package the application. It's not used at runtime. I don't know minecraft, but I guess spigot.jar is in the runtime classpath of minecraft.

Comment: The answer is no, transitive dependencies are not loaded correctly by FML.  It appears that Minecraft modding is hostile toward modularity.