# Why can't I find aSmack in Maven Central?

Tags: android, smack, asmack

Here I find all resources to build my own aSmack jar, correct?
https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack

But how can I put the aSmack jar (version 4.0.6) in my Maven/Gradle application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I haven't uploaded it to OSS Sonatype, so it won't show up on Maven Central. :-)

You can add aSmack to gradle like any other jar library. See [Add external jar in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734314/add-external-jar-in-gradle)

Answer (score 1):

### Read the `README.MD`:

https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack

### It says:

> Smack 4.1 adds native support for Android
>
> Starting with Version 4.1 Smack is able to run without modifications
>   on Android. Smack 4.1 is currently in a alpha development stage.
>   Snapshots and alpha releases are on Maven Central. Everyone is invited
>   to test and provide feedback.
>
> More information on how to use Smack 4.1 in your Android Project can
>   be found in the Smack 4.1 Readme and Upgrade Guide.
>
> Compiled JARs Make sure to read the README for every release! Or else
>   aSmack won't work for you. 95% of the problems people experiencing
>   with aSmack come from the fact that they didn't read the README.
>
> The JARs can be found @ http://asmack.freakempire.de/

### Leads you here:

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

### and then:

Projects that target Android

With Gradle

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
  }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Smack configuration with smack-extensions for XMPP over TCP

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-beta1"
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-beta1"
}
```

Minimal Smack configuration for XMPP over TCP

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-beta1"
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-beta1"
}
```